# How to open a web site after uninstallation?

Tags: inno-setup

I can open a web site after software installation like this:

```
[Run]
Filename: "http://example.com"; Flags: shellexec runasoriginaluser
```

Is there a way to open another web site after software uninstallation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For opening a non-executable file after the uninstallation finishes I would write this:

```
[Code]
const
  UninstSiteURL = 'http://example.com/uninstalled.html';

procedure CurUninstallStepChanged(CurUninstallStep: TUninstallStep);
var
  ErrorCode: Integer;
begin
  if CurUninstallStep = usDone then
    ShellExec('', UninstSiteURL, '', '', SW_SHOW, ewNoWait, ErrorCode);
end;
```

Comment: Be sure to make this optional. If I want to get rid of something, the last thing I want it doing is popping up its website asking me why.

Comment: Note that this opens the browser with Administrator permissions, if the uninstaller is running elevated. You should avoid that. See [How to open a web site after uninstallation in non-elevated mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63614641/850848)